# How to combine multiple datasets into one in R?

Tags: r

I have 3 text files each of which has 14 similar columns. I want to first read these 3 files (data frames) and then combine them into one data frame. Following is what I have tried after finding some help in R mailing list:

```
file_name <- list.files(pattern='sEMA*')  # CREATING A LIST OF FILE NAMES OF FILES HAVING 'sEMA' IN THEIR NAMES
NGSim <- lapply (file_name, read.csv, sep=' ', header=F, strip.white=T) # READING ALL THE TEXT FILES
```

This piece of code can read the files altogether but does not combine them into one data frame. I have tried `data.frame(NGSim)` but R gives an error: cannot allocate vector of size 4.2 Mb. How can I combine the files in one single data frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(plyr)
rbind.fill(NGSim)
```

or,

```
ldply(NGSim)
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
do.call(rbind, NGSim)
```

Comment: The above function results in Error: cannot allocate vector of size 29.8 Mb

Comment: try starting a new R session.

Answer (score 0):

If file size is an issue that's the case you may want to the use `data.table` functions instead of less efficient base functions like `read.csv()`.

```
library(data.table)
NGSim <- data.frame(rbindlist(lapply(list.files(pattern='sEMA*'),fread)))
```

Comment: I am getting this error: Error in FUN(c("sEMA-0750am-0805am.txt", "sEMA-0805am-0820am.txt", "sEMA-0820am-0835am.txt" : 
  Expected sep (' ') but '
' ends field 36 on line 28 when detecting types:  1731  397 5135  721   7.0   5.5  1  40.57   3.33     1